# Devise, StripeConnect, Doorkeeper, OAuth2

Tags: devise, oauth-2.0, omniauth, stripe-payments

I am developing a CrowdFunding site and want to choose the best combination of things for the MerchantService side.  I have been in contact with Stripe and they believe that they would be a good fit, and after speaking with them I decided to give them a try. Brian C, I saw a couple weeks back that you use Stripe for your clients...thoughts?

I am reaching out to ask for advice on the set up.

1. I am using Devise & StripeConnect - I know I need OAuth2 but ought I use Doorkeeper too.
2. What are some thoughts on the best way to set these up? Any sample code out there to look through?
3. Should I use ( gem 'omniauth-stripe-connect' ) or is there a better solution?
4. If yes to #3 do I need all three ( gem 'omniauth') & ( gem oauth2 ) & ( gem 'omniauth-stripe-connect' )

Thanks in advance - Jason

Comment: Here are a few posts regarding issues you might stumble upon.. see
https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/?s=doorkeeper

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of links that I've found helpful in getting off the ground.

[Rails Apps tutorial - stripe-membership-SaaS recipe](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-stripe-membership-saas.html)

This screencast doesn't cover webhooks, but was a lot of help getting me started in my understanding.

[Railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?view=asciicast/%20%22Railscasts.com)

Hope these links help.

Ramon

Comment: Ramon, I have Stripe working via the RailsCast, but I am trying to figure out how the best way get StripeConnect going.